# Cannot set color to pixels of image

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to set the color for some area in the image, pixel by pixel. But I'm always getting white.

How can I correct this behavior?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def f():
    img = np.zeros([1000, 1000, 3])
    color = np.array([50, 100, 200])
    for y in range(500):
        for x in range(500):
            img[x][y] = color
    img_name = "CA"
    cv2.imshow(img_name, img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

f()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not specifying the correct datatype:

```
img = np.zeros([1000, 1000, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
color = np.array([50, 100, 200], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Comment: Python version: dtype=np.uint8

Comment: Goodness, I'm not sure how I managed to write `uint.8` without noticing.